# thead, tbody and tfoot background images not displaying in chrome

Tags: html, css

```
table 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead 
{
    background: url('../images/theadimage.png') 365px bottom no-repeat;
}

tbody 
{
    background: url('../images/tbodyimage.png') 365px top repeat-y;
}

tfoot 
{
    background: url('../images/tfootimage1.png') 365px top no-repeat, url('../images/tfootimage2.png') 0px -8px repeat-x;
}
```

This is displaying the images correctly positioned in all browsers except chrome (oddly). If I change the tbody to repeat-x I see the image, but when set to no-repeat or repeat-y, the background images are completely disappearing.

What am I missing here? Is there a solution or a workaround for chrome?

Comment: what is the `365px` supposed to mean?

Comment: left position offset of the background image.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page with this so we can examine it?

Comment: @hotSauce.Open Create a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem

Comment: [This looks like a known issue in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35697). It appears that the workaround is to display table cells as inline-blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching I discovered this is a [known issue in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35697) and the workaround that worked for me and still maintained proper rendering in all other browsers was to render `td` and `th` elements as inline-block and `tr` elements as block. Adding the following CSS to that mentioned in the original question was the solution that worked for me.

```
table.problemTable tr {
    display: block;
}
table.problemTable td, table.problemTable th {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, you need to specify style in tfoot tr {} instead of tfoot {}. same method applies to all.

**CSS**

```
tfoot{ background: url(tfoot.gif) no-repeat; width: 604px !important; // 604 is width of table}
tr {background: #e0e0e0;}
tfoot tr {background: url(tfoot.gif) no-repeat; width: 604px; display: table;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table><thead><tr><th>Header 1</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>Body cell</td></tr></tbody>
<tfoot><tr><td>Footer Cell </tr></tfoot></table>
```

Hope this will help you... All the best